# IEEE tran resizing the table

Tags: tables, ieeetran

How do I get rid of this situation?

[image]

The code for creating the table is :

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{LCS Grammar for the Web Portal}
    \begin{tabular}{rrr}
    \toprule
    \textbf{GRAMMAR} & \textbf{EXPLANATION } & \textbf{CHANGE REQUEST} \\
    \midrule
    L→(S1.S2).((S3.S4)*S5) & S1 = Login & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    S1→OP1 & S2 = Pay Landline Bills & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    S2→OP2 & S3 = Register For New Services & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    S3→OP3 & S4 = Get Status & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    S4→OP4 & S5 = View Bills & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    S5→OP5 & OP1=get\_credentials & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(op1.op2).((op3.op4)*op6)} \\
    S6→OP6 & OP2= get\_card details &  \\
          & OP3=get\_custdetails &  \\
          & OP4=get\_notification &  \\
          & OP5=get\_bill &  \\
          & OP6=get\_usage &  \\
          &       &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:lcsgrammar}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.7     \toprule` Please, at least **try to compile your MWE before asking a question!**

Comment: Use `\begin{table*}` instead of `\begin{table}[htbp]` and `\end{table*}` instead of `\end{table}`: your table doesn't fit in a column, so you have to use a double column float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no chance that table fits in one column. Use the `table*` two column float type.

I have also changed the alignments to left.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newunicodechar{→}{$\to$}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table*}
\centering

\caption{LCS Grammar for the Web Portal}
\label{tab:lcsgrammar}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
\textbf{GRAMMAR} & \textbf{EXPLANATION } & \textbf{CHANGE REQUEST} \\
\midrule
L→(S1.S2).((S3.S4)*S5) & S1 = Login & \\
S1→OP1 & S2 = Pay Landline Bills & \\
S2→OP2 & S3 = Register For New Services & \\
S3→OP3 & S4 = Get Status & \\
S4→OP4 & S5 = View Bills & \\
S5→OP5 & OP1 = get\_credentials & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(op1.op2).((op3.op4)*op6)} \\
S6→OP6 & OP2 = get\_card details &  \\
       & OP3 = get\_custdetails &  \\
       & OP4 = get\_notification &  \\
       & OP5 = get\_bill &  \\
       & OP6 = get\_usage &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

[image]